# Display a sum of numbers one number at a time

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

As a non-expert, I am creating a math exercise for kids on Excel using VBA. The idea is to display a sum of numbers on the screen, for example 3+5+2, but I want the numbers to appear one at a time with a pause of 2 seconds between each number. Also, each number that appears replaces the previous one on the screen. Concretely...

- "3" appears for 2 seconds then disappears
- "+5" appears for 2 seconds then disappears
- "+2" appears for 2 seconds then disappears

I have tried two methods that failed :

1. using multiple long loops to 'waste' time between each number

   ```
   Range("A1").Value = "3"

   for a=1 to 20

      for b=1 to 10000

         for c=1 to 10000

         Next

      Next

   Next

   Range("A1").Value = "'" & "+5"

   'etc
   ```

(I couldn't write a huge number like 100000000 which is why I had to do multiple loops)

2. using the wait application

   ```
   Range("A1").Value = "3"

   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

   Range("A1").Value = "'" & "+5"

   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

   Range("A1").Value = "'" & "+2"

   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

   Range("A1").Value = ""
   ```

In both cases, the process works in step-by-step execution (using F8) but acts weirdly when executed normally... numbers mostly don't appear, sometimes one does, and I can't figure out why.
I have tried with larger waiting values, still the numbers don't appear.
I haven't tried the sleep application because I would like to understand what is happening here.

I apologize in advance if my question is poorly written/formulated.

Comment: Your second examples seems to work fine for me - didn't try the first one as the second would be the way to go.  Is there any other code involved?  Turning off screen updating?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is no other code involved for that specific action. It seems that, because I add a blank value at the end of that second code, the "+2" only appears for a fraction of a second. The blanks seem to be the problem, as if the waiting time didn't take effect. When I only display numbers, it works fine. It's the same if I use ClearContents instead of a blank. Ideally, I would like to have a blank in between each number, so I have to figure out why this happens. BTW, how do I turn off screen updating ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
Sub MathGame()
    Dim numberOfInputs As Integer
    
    numberOfInputs = 2
    
    For i = 0 To numberOfInputs
        Range("A1") = Range("A1") & " + " & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 9)
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    Next i
End Sub
```

To increase or decrease the difficulty you can either:

1. Update the `numberofInputs`
2. Update the parameters for `RandBetween`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This code works, although the new number doesn't replace the previous one, it comes next to it. I could adapt it though. It works, as long as I don't add a blank at the end. Whenever there is a blank, the previous display only goes for a fraction of a second. That is the problem, as I would like to have the cell cleared in between the display of each number and also at the end. I should have been more specific about that...

Comment: You just need this line `Range("A1") = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 9)` instead of `Range("A1") = Range("A1") & " + " & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 9)`